# stuck at dart sdk downloading while setup the flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, flutter-web

### Steps to Reproduce

Whenever I tried to run any flutter or dart on cmd after installing the git bash it's start download the dart SDK again even I already set up it. I used flutter for nearly 7 8 months but I never face a problem like this recently I reset my pc and setup flutter again but this time it's not setup

**Steps I will do for installing the flutter**

1. download the Dart SDK and setup path in a user variable and run dart --version so it works fine its show the current dart version
2. After I setup flutter SDK similar to dart but after run dart --version and it again works fine and shows the current version or if I run any flutter command like flutter doctor its shows an error like this
   Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.
3. To resolve this error I install git
   **Now the problem has come **
4. Again when I run the dart --version its work fine but if I tried to run flutter doctor or any flutter command its start downloading the Dart SDK

Output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1379]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\prash>dart --version
Dart SDK version: 2.10.5 (stable) (Tue Jan 19 13:05:37 2021 +0100) on "windows_x64"

C:\Users\prash>flutter doctor
Checking Dart SDK version...
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine 2f0af3715217a0c2ada72c717d4ed9178d68f6ed...
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

C:\Users\prash>dart --version
Dart SDK version: 2.10.5 (stable) (Tue Jan 19 13:05:37 2021 +0100) on "windows_x64"
```

Please help so to fix this I doesn't want to download the dart SDK if I already setup its

Answer (score -1):

run in terminal:

```
Flutter upgrade --force
```